# Fetch data from Excel to Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from an excel file. I defined the function which read the data but I cannot figure out how to show it in a list view. Please help

```
class DataRow {
  String dni;
  String nombre;

  DataRow(this.dni, this.nombre);
}

void read() async {
  List<DataRow> list = [];
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("db/Propuestas.xlsx");
  var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
  var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

  for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
    print(table);
    for (var row in excel.tables[table]!.rows) {
      if (row.isNotEmpty) {
        DataRow data = DataRow(row[0], row[1]);
        list.add(data);
      }
    }
  }
}

class DataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DataScreenState createState() => DataScreenState();
}

class DataScreenState extends State<DataScreen> {
  List<DataRow> list = []; // somewhere set the values for this
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(children: [
            Text(list[index].dni),
            Text(list[index].nombre),
          ]);
        });
  }
}
```

and the login button that triggers the navigation to DataScreen:

```
Widget _bottonLogin() {
  return StreamBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
        ))),
        
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0, vertical: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              'Iniciar sesión',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Calibri'),
            
            )
            ),
            onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => **DataScreen()**
              )
            );
    });
  });
}
```

this is the implementation you suggested me but it is not showing any data yet. Please help me out with this last thing.

Comment: Put the `read()` between ` List<DataRow> list = []; // somewhere set the values for this` and `@override Widget build(BuildContext context){...}`, also remove the `List<DataRow> list = [];` line from `read()` method.

Comment: Also add this to your `DataScreenState` class: `void initState() {read();}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a data class:
For example:

```
class DataRow {
  String name;
  int age;

  DataRow(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Then extract the data out of the rows and store them in a list:

```
List<DataClass> list = [];

for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
    print(table);
    for (var row in excel.tables[table]!.rows ) {
      if (row.isNotEmpty) {
        DataRow data = DataRow(...); // No idea how to work with excels
        list.add(data);
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can build your screen:

```
class DataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DataScreenState createState() => DataScreenState();
}

class DataScreenState extends State<DataScreen>{

 List<DataClass> list = []; // somewhere set the values for this
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount = list.length,     
     itemBuilder:
     (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return Column(children: [Text(list[index].name), Text(list[index].age),]);
    
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you cleared a bit my mind with this but it is still not showing any data. I edited my post with your implementation and the login button. Where could it be the error?